# Countable limit ordinal as limit of $\omega$ ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I've got a most probably silly question, but I can't find the answer to it:

If $\alpha$ is a countable limit ordinal, how can we be sure that there exist ordinals $\alpha_n$ such that $\alpha = \bigcup \{\alpha_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ (rather than the usual $\alpha = \bigcup \{\beta\mid \beta<\alpha\}$)?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all $\{\beta\mid\beta<\alpha\}=\alpha$ is countable, therefore it can be enumerated as $\alpha_n$'s. But I suppose that you want to ask about a strictly increasing sequence.

First enumerate $\alpha$ as $\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$. Then by induction define $\alpha_n$, where $\alpha_{n+1}=\beta_k$ where $k=\min\{m\mid\alpha_n<\beta_m\}$. You can now show that this is a strictly increasing and cofinal sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to ordinals and while I know (knew) that countable things can be enumerated as $\alpha_n$'s, I am now unsure why we can do so using only $\omega$, and not, say, $\omega^2$ indices to do so. Is that the definition of countability? Sorry for all the stupid questions.

Comment: Well, being countable is by definition to have an injection into $\omega$, or in other words to be enumerated.

Comment: Okay, in this case I'm fine. It's just weird how I am now unsure about so many things in set theory I didn't even think I could be unsure about a few weeks ago... :-)

Comment: It's the graph of learning. Wait, you'll be sure again and then unsure again and then sure again... and so on and so forth.

Comment: He he, so true. Anyway, thanks heaps again for helping me now for the second time!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm [probably](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/elementary-set-theory/topusers) gonna help you [again](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/ordinals/topusers) in the future.